# How to reinstall Calendar Storage?

Tags: root-access, calendar, uninstallation

I wanted to uninstall the default Calendar app to replace with Google Calendar. However, I accidentally uninstalled Calendar Storage before uninstalled the default Calendar app. The Google Calendar app won't work every time I try to create an event/plan. I assume this is because I uninstalled the Calendar Storage (app?).

How do I retrieve it? Is there a repo wherein I can just download it? I tried Googling, found nothing. My phone is a Huwawei Y320, Android OS version is 4.2.2

Comment: Is your phone rooted ?

Comment: Yes, phone's rooted.

Comment: @rjt.rockx you cannot uninstall calendar storage without root :) // OP: if you didn't make a backup beforehand, you're pretty much doomed: unless you can find someone with the same device and ROM (to obtain the deleted files from), you most likely will have to flash your ROM again. And no, almost no calendar app will work without the calendar storage – as that's an OS service most expect to be simply there.

Comment: Whew! My mom has the exact device. How do I "send" her Calendar Storage to my phone?

Comment: @Izzy, it can be done. I just installed the Kitkat version on my device, and when I tried to uninstall it, it got uninstalled directly, although it was a system app. Could be a glitch or something for specific phones. My present one wasn't rooted. To solve a problem, you have to experience it first. Precisely why I tried out my answer before posting it here. No need to worry, it worked out. Safety First :)

Comment: This should help http://rktool.blogspot.in/2014/08/lg-d802-422-stock-firmware-guide-how-to.html?m=1  It also talks of installing a part of ROM

Comment: Thanks so much the link http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/104979/uninstalled-calendar-storage-google-calendar-not-working worked ! ! !

Answer (score 1):

You will have to download [this](http://download.apks.org/download2.php?ver=4.2.2-573038&apkid=com.android.providers.calendar&server=8&download=apk) app and install it as a system app, using Link2SD or any similar app. This is just another apk file from another Android Jelly Bean 4.2.2 phone.

Note : Please backup all your data before trying to do so. This way of installing apps is actually not recommended, but works out most of the times.

Comment: By the way, this does work, I have done it with my own device several times. Once, I even deleted SystemUI.apk, thinking it was unnecessary. When I realised my mistake, I installed it by creating a recovery script and flashing the app to the system/apps/ partition. It worked for stock AOSP, but custom ROMs are a doubt. Calendar Storage isn't linked in that way, so it is pretty much the same across almost all phones having the same Android version.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded this file: http://download.apks.org/?server=12&apkid=com.android.providers.calendar&ver=4.4.4-a1d45e8141

EDIT: This is for Android 4.4.4.  If you have another version of Android just do a Google search for the apk file.  Then, get it from a site you trust.  Also,  I have android 5.1, and it still worked,  so there's a possibility that it might work if you have a newer version of Android.

Next, I installed the apk file from the downloads folder.

Finally, I downloaded a /system/app mover from the Google play store (requires root), and made the calendar storage app a system app.

I rebooted, and now my calendar works perfectly!

Comment: Note that the provided link downloads the Calendar Provider for Android 4.4.4 (KitKat) while OP's version is Android 4.2.2 (JellyBean). **Always install the same version as your Android**, since different version may have different structure and incompatible with your device (source: self-experience on digging Android Calendar structure's source)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did in a LG L90:

First, I went to Settings > About Phone > Common > Update Center > App Updates. Then I looked for the disabled app. There it was, Calendar Storage. I had to reinstall it, and then the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

If you found this question via google because you deleted your Samsung Calendar Storage APK and your calendar app no longer works, then try this.  None of the above methods worked for me, so don't waste your time.

**REQUIREMENTS**

1. The original state of the ROM before you deleted the APK.  This can be in the form of a TWRP backup or you can flash the original, identical ROM you currently are using.
2. ES File Explorer
3. Root access - but you most likely already have this because you can't delete a system APK without root and you wouldn't be here in the first place.

**PROCEDURE - PART 1**

1. Do a TWRP backup of the current state of your phone.
2. Hopefully, you made a TWRP backup before you started debloating your phone, if so, restore that backup -OR- reflash your original ROM.
3. After you're done restoring or flashing, install ES File Explorer
4. Open ES File Explorer
5. Touch the "menu" button (3 horizontal lines)
6. Touch "Root Explorer"
7. Touch "Backup app and data"
8. Touch "User Apps" dropdown, select "System apps"
9. Touch & Hold "Calendar storage"
10. Touch "Backup" on the bottom bar

**PROCEDURE - PART 2**

1. Go into TWRP and restore your phone back to its current state, using the backup that you just created.
2. After you're done restoring, reboot phone
3. Install ES File Explorer if you don't already have it
4. Open ES File Explorer
5. Touch the "menu" button (3 horizontal lines)
6. Touch "Root Explorer"
7. Touch "Backup app and data"
8. Touch "User Apps" dropdown, select "Backed-up Apps"
9. Touch & Hold "Calendar storage"
10. Touch "3 Dots" button on the bottom bar
11. Touch "Install"

Done!

Comment: *DO NOT* use ES File Explorer. It has been involved in spam/malware incidents and displaying other suspicious behavior a handful of times in the last couple of years: https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/es-file-explorer-malware-dianxin-folder-t3348545

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your mum has es file explorer ( not necessarily if she has root) launch the app and on the default screen tap apps. All her users app should open .you should see a section at the left top where it says apps tap on it and select system. There you should find the app you are looking for . Long press on the app and tap the sharing icon .share Bluetooth or whatever. You may want to install before converting . Or you may just enable root explorer in es file explorer along the dashboard  copy the apk file. Go to the es file explorer dashboard , tap local , select device , go to system , app, and paste it there  then reboot  .`

Comment: "launch the app" - which app?

Comment: *DO NOT* use ES File Explorer. It has been involved in spam/malware incidents and displaying other suspicious behavior a handful of times in the last couple of years: https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/es-file-explorer-malware-dianxin-folder-t3348545

Answer (score 0):

When debloating your phone, it's likely that you have to use an app for uninstalling root apps. Check if your app has a recycling bin. If you have, then restore it from there and restart your phone.

The app I use is System App Safe Remove.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Here's an update for lollipop+. I did the same. 
Downloaded this http://download.apks.org/?apkid=com.android.providers.calendar&ver=5.1.1-981c9024fa&server=darkkiller
Install-Moved to system-reboot. Job done :)

Comment: App cannot install